# select max record for each employee

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got an employee rates table in MS Access.  I would like to select the latest/max rates record for each employee:

```
ID(Autonumber)   
EmployeeID
EmployeeRate

So for example for employee nr 3 there would be
ID(Autonumber)   EmployeeID    EmployeeRate
1                3             100.00
2                3             150.00
3                10            110.00
4                10            160.00
```

How do I select records 2 and 4?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.EmployeeID, MAX(a.EmployeeRate)
FROM YourTable AS a
GROUP BY a.EmployeeID;
```

Answer (score 0):

well latest vs max rates are 2 different concepts. This should get you the latest rate for the employee.

If you want latest do something like this

```
select EmployeeID, EmployeeRate from YourTable a
join (select EmployeeID as EmployeeID , max(id) as id from YourTable group by EmployeeID) b on b.id=a.id
```

Comment: Good point. Want to expand on your comments in your answer to tell OP that he would need a date field or some indicator to identify a rating as "most recent" ?